# how to grouping mysql columns with conditions

Tags: mysql

![ a    b    c     d     e

16 14 1 0 0 
  16 14 0 1 0 
  16 14 0 0 1 
  16 15 1 0 0 
  16 15 0 1 0 
  16 15 0 0 1 
](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y6bMqEJ-i5MXmUq89APv7aSLDOXFbwWy)

how can i get like
 a    b  c  d  e 
 16  14 1 1 1
 16 15 1 1 1

Comment: please specify what you are trying in detail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to aggregate on the combination of the `a` and `b` columns, and then take the sum of the `c`, `d`, and `e` columns.

```
SELECT a, b, SUM(c) AS c, SUM(d) AS d, SUM(e) AS e
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY a, b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Some what like group by columns a and b and from rest of the columns pick maximum values

```
select a ,b,max(c) c,max(d) d,max(e) e
from table1
group by a,b
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0235e/2)

> If you need sum see @Tim's answer

Comment: This may be the best answer here depending on the OP's planned use of the query.